# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a long press gesture on my table view cell (only have 1 row) and it opens a popup. When I dismiss this popup, and tap on the cell again, somehow it doesn't register the first tap. The cell `touchesBegan` does get called but in `tableView.didSelectRowAtIndexPath` won't get called for the first tap.

What could be the cause of this?

I've tried:

- failing the gesture recognizers of the table view
- reload the table view
- using the delegate methods of the recognizer
- using a button to open the popup does not have this problem

**Summary:**

- UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UITableViewCell to open popup
- After dismissing the popup, the **first** tap on the table view cell:

  - UITableViewCell touchesBegan gets called
  - tableView.didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

---

The code:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: VC1Delegate? { didSet { addGestureRecognizer(detailsGesture) } }

    lazy var detailsGesture: gesture = {
        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self.delegate, action: #selector(VC1.openPopup)) 
        gesture.delegate = self
        return gesture
    }()

    // Setup of the view cell
}

class VC1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, VC1Delegate {

    func openPopup(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .Began {
            // Open popup
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("cell tapped")
    }
}
```

After endless trying and testing it turns out the problem is caused by:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Any idea why having scroll disabled causes this problem?

Another "fix" is by calling without calling it's super:

```
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { }
```

But I'm not sure if I should do that.

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Of course. I just don't think the code would be useful and make the question unnecessarily long. Give me a second.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ paste your code here.

Comment: it gets print when you tap?

Comment: To be exact, after dismissing the popup, the first tap won't print. After that, it just behaves normally.

Comment: It feels like, after using the long press gesture, the tap isn't being finished and have to tap the tableview to finish the tap to proceed? Does that make any sense?

Comment: Turns out the culprit was the line: `scrollEnabled = false` (which I thought wasn't relevant so I didn't add it to the question). Do you know why having scroll disabled causing this?

Comment: Why you are using touchesBegan Method..?? Can you show me the touchesBegan Method ...?